# Multiple Jssor sliders in one page, with slide counters

Tags: slider, counter, jssor

**Problem description**:

I implement Jssor slider in a Joomla2.5 system. I put the Jssor code on the template level (a custom template) inside two files which i link from the template's 'index.php':

a. 'template.js' where i include the jssor code ('no jquery' option, jssor.slider.min.js and the "jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {...}")

b. 'template.css' where i include the css.

Inside Joomla articles, i put the sliders, when and where i want them.
OK, fine. Everything works till here. Gorgeous.

I want the sliders with slider counter. In the Joomla CMS, according to the many ways the articles are normally presented, it is of course possible that multiple instances of Jssor sliders come in a single page. Here i have it, the counters mess with each other.

**My homework:**

Inside the 'jssor_slider1_starter' function:

```
...
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
function DisplayIndex() {$("#displayIndex").text(jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex() + 1 + " / " + jssor_slider1.$SlidesCount());}
DisplayIndex();
jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, DisplayIndex);
```

Inside the Joomla article, inside the slider:

```
<div id="displayIndex" data-u="any" class="index"></div>
```

Note: the above bit put just before

```
<script>jssor_slider1_starter('slider_name');</script>
```

since i want the counter absolutely positioned below the slider inner container.

As far as i can see, the problem lies in the presence of multiple "displayIndex" ids in the page, which is abnormal.
So i thought, i may cut off this bit from 'template.js':

```
function DisplayIndex() {$("#displayIndex").text(jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex() + 1 + " / " + jssor_slider1.$SlidesCount());}
DisplayIndex();
jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, DisplayIndex);
```

and put it inside every slider specifically, like this for example:

```
<script>jssor_slider1_starter('This_slider');
function DisplayIndexThis_slider() {$("#displayIndexThis_slider").text(jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex() + 1 + " / " + jssor_slider1.$SlidesCount());}
DisplayIndexThis_slider();
jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, DisplayIndexThis_slider);
</script>
```

Somewhere here i killed the thing. I fiddled quite a bit... but it seems to be beyond my skills.

Answer (score 1):

The working code (for every slider instance) is:

```
<script>
slider_name_starter = function (containerId) {
var options={$ArrowNavigatorOptions: {$Class:$JssorArrowNavigator$,$ChanceToShow:2}};
var jssor_slider_name=new $JssorSlider$(containerId,options);
function DisplayIndex(){$("#" + containerId + "_Index").text(jssor_slider_name.$CurrentIndex() + 1 + " / " + jssor_slider_name.$SlidesCount());}
DisplayIndex();jssor_slider_name.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, DisplayIndex);};
</script>

<div class="slider" id="slider_name">

<!--Loading-screen-->...<!--Loading-screen-->

<!--container-->
<div data-u="slides" class="slides">

<!--slides-->...

</div><!--container-->

<!-- Arrows -->
<span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style=""></span>
<span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style=""></span>

<!-- index -->
<div id="slider_name_Index" data-u="any" class=""></div>

<script>slider_name_starter('slider_name');</script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    This_slider_starter = function (containerId) {
        var options = { };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);

        function DisplayIndex() {
            $("#" + containerId + "_Index").text(jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex() + 1 + " of " + jssor_slider1.$SlidesCount());
        }

        DisplayIndex();
        jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, DisplayIndex);
    };
</script>

<script>
    That_slider_starter = function (containerId) {
        var options = { };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);

        function DisplayIndex() {
            $("#" + containerId + "_Index").text(jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex() + 1 + " of " + jssor_slider1.$SlidesCount());
        }

        DisplayIndex();
        jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, DisplayIndex);
    };
</script>

<div id="This_slider" ...>
    ...
    <div u="slides" ...>
        ...

        <div id="This_slider_Index" u="any" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; width: 100px; height: 26px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    This_slider_starter('This_slider');
</script>

<div id="That_slider" ...>
    ...
    <div u="slides" ...>
        ...

        <div id="That_slider_Index" u="any" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; width: 100px; height: 26px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    That_slider_starter('That_slider');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the amazingly quick response. I will say that despite struggling i did not make it, so i paste the slider's code hoping to spot the mistake(s):

```
<script>This_slider_starter = function (containerId) {
var options = { };
var jssor_This_slider = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
function DisplayIndex(){$("#" + containerId + "Index").text(jssor_This_slider.$CurrentIndex() + 1 + " of " + jssor_This_slider.$SlidesCount());}
DisplayIndex();
jssor_This_slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, DisplayIndex);
};
</script>

<div class="slider" id="This_slider">

<!--Loading-screen-->
<div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
<div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url('images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">&nbsp;</div>
</div><!--Loading-screen-->

<!--container-->
<div data-u="slides" class="slides">

...

</div><!--container-->

<!-- Arrows -->
<span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 450px; left: 0px;"></span>
<span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 450px; right: 0px"></span>

<!-- index -->
<div id="This_slider_Index" data-u="any" class="index"></div>

<script>This_slider_starter('This_slider');</script>

</div>
```

Comment: You should move `<div id="This_slider_Index"` into the `<div data-u="slides"` container.

Comment: I think inside or outside does not matter. S. updated code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Still struggling.

I *think* you made a mistake: `"#" + containerId + "Index"` must become `"#" + containerId + "_Index"`.

The below code makes the index work (*outside or inside container*):

```
<script>
This_slider_starter = function (containerId) {
var options = { };
var jssor_This_slider = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
function DisplayIndex(){$("#" + containerId + "_Index").text(jssor_This_slider.$CurrentIndex() + 1 + " of " + jssor_This_slider.$SlidesCount());}
DisplayIndex();
jssor_This_slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, DisplayIndex);
};
</script>

<div class="slider" id="This_slider">

<!--container-->
<div data-u="slides" class="slides">

<!--slides-->
...

</div><!--container-->

<!-- Arrows -->
<span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 450px; left: 0px;"></span>
<span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 450px; right: 0px"></span>

<!-- index -->
<div id="This_slider_Index" data-u="any" class="index"></div>

<script>This_slider_starter('This_slider');</script>

</div>
```

The problem: the arrows do not work.

Comment: Please add  css for arrows, and add $ArrowNavigatorOptions option. Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-arrow-navigator-jquery.html

Comment: Everythink OK. Thank You! -- I'll now post final working code as an answer.